# Behavior of the temporal part of the wavefunction in an infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

I have a question about the behavior of the temporal part of the wavefunction in an infinite well. For reference, the solution given in my textbook for the wavefunction of a particle in an infinite well with 0 potential inside the well is :
$$\phi(t)=e^{{-iEt}/{\hbar}}$$
$$\psi(x)=\sqrt{2/{L}}\sin({n\pi x}/L)$$
The derivation of these solutions makes sense to me. But I got confused after seeing this diagram of the standing waves in an infinite well. The diagram is supposed to show the wavefunction as a function of position.
The faint lines are supposed to show that these are standing waves and they come about due to temporal part of the wavefunction. Since the temporal part of the wavefunction is multiplied with the spatial part to give the full wavefunction $$\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x)\phi(t)$$

If we choose some non zero point and input it into the full wavefunction, and let time vary, we should be able to see the behavior of the wavefunction at that point as time changes. Since the temporal part can never equal zero because the exponential will never give 0, how exactly does the wavefunction evolve? If it is supposed to be a standing wave, how does it go from the maximum value to the minimum value if it is not supposed to be equal to zero at any point? Since it has to be continuous it can't just switch between maximum and minimum correct? So how does it go from a positive point to a negative point if it can never be zero? What mistakes am I making in my reasoning here?

[image: diagram of wavefunction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how does it go from a positive point to a negative point if it can never be zero?

The wavefunction is complex.  At a given point it has a value of $A e^{-i E_n t/\hbar}$.  So if its value at a particular time is $A$, then a quarter-cycle later it becomes $-i A$; a half-cycle after the start it's $-A$;  and 3/4 of a cycle after the start its value is $i A$.

Comment: Oh, OK that makes a lot sense, thank you!!

Comment: Since this question has such a simple answer, I'd point out that this is intimately related to the failure of mean value theorem for complex functions, so that students get an extra understanding.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent , could I ask how to think about the wavefunction with complex exponentials in the right way? Since this is a 2 dimensional infinite well, the wavefunction must have some value at every point right? What does it mean for it to have a complex value at some point? I am having a hard time intuitively visualizing a complex function in 2 dimensions .

Comment: There is simply no nice way to think of it; you kinda have to learn to accept complex numbers as they are. For myself, I think of it as a rotating wave. Kinda like when you get a string to vibrate as a standing wave, you could do the same shape if you make it a rotating standing wave rather than vibrating standing wave.